# how can changed font color in text area which contains special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have textarea and i want to change the font color of some text which contains the #(hashtag)
i want to do this by using jquery when enter #(hashtag) then change the color of that word

```
<textarea name="community" id="community" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="X happens">this s is test text #photography in this string word #photography should be in different color</textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: yes i have try more and also search for this but not getting any things

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: I think @Regent is trying to tell you to show what you have come up with for now ;-) Show your JS code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i change hashtag color on textarea by jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517448/how-can-i-change-hashtag-color-on-textarea-by-jquery)

Comment: You can't change particular word color in textarea, because you can't put html tags in textarea element... You can use a rich text editor or simply a div with contenteditable=true (if your project is ok for html5).

Comment: And there is old-fashioned solution with replacing `<textarea>` with `<div>`. Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqnwd9ek/).

Comment: its changed from textarea to div but tag color still not changed when i am entering the test its changed the color of text when it is completed, but i need to change the font color at the time of entering the text